# Library to develop web-based spreadsheet, compatible with Excel and PDF

Tags: open-source, web-development, microsoft-excel, google-apps, open-office

I'm looking for open source library's which can make own web editor for editing excel sheets like Google Spread sheet.

I want webify the excel sheet & Pdf as web application.

Are there any Open sources & Commercial library's or API's are available?

Comment: Which language will you be coding in?

Comment: Do you require editing, or just viewing? (for Excel and PDF)

Comment: I'm looking for both. @Nicolas, Are there any with either?

Comment: preferably JS or If not in JS would like to adopt any lang. @Mawg

Comment: @Narendra The one I know does only viewing. Also, it requires a server-side Java component to transform documents and serve them page-by-page (so that the browser does not have to download a 100 MB PDF just to show the first page). Is a required server-side component acceptable? Or do you need a 100% client-based solution?

Comment: Yes, acceptable, I feel its secure way also form server side rendering.